# AVD not starting in Ubuntu 16.04 and Android 2.3

Tags: 16.04, android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to start AVD in Android Studio but I can't. When I start AVD it doesn't throw any error but while launching the application it says `waiting for device to come online` and then closes after a few seconds. I tried to install `lib64stdc++6` but I get unmet dependencies:

[image: ScreenShot of the problem]

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me.

This is because of a bad libstdc file Android sdk.

1. Download the deb file from here
2. Extract files using archieve utility
3. Copy and replace the libstdc file in the Android sdk folder with the
   one from deb.

Deb Download link - 
http://ftp.kr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-7/libstdc++6_7.2.0-4_amd64.deb

Sdk folder paths -

/SDK-FOLDER/emulator/lib/libstdc++

/SDK-FOLDER/emulator/lib64/libstdc++